# Virtual DOM and Real DOM steps for simple operation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

i read a lot about VirualDOM.
all articles explain how the VirtualDOM calculate change and then change the real DOM in efficient steps.
but they dont explain how react paint the element in the realDOM? they use the official API? ('document.createElement', appendChild, etc...)?

so they says RealDOM is slow and if you change something in your realDOM he re-render the whole DOM.

so for example:

**simple HTML markup:**

```
<ul class="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
<ul>
```

**simple script:**

```
const li = document.createElement('li');
document.querySelector('.list').appendChild(li);
```

Questions:

1) this operation will re-paint the whole DOM?

2) in this simple operation how react will be faster?

3) after react calculate the VirtualDOM vs RealDOM how react paint on realDOM? react use the browser API? or they have other way?

thanks for all! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual DOM (VueJs, ReactJs and other) is only abstraction level of a DOM. This means, that elementary operations in Virtual DOM always slower than DOM. But Virtual DOM and component approach help to manage DOM tree effectively in large SPA applications.
Basically, Virtual DOM allows you to **minimize the need to re-layout** and re-paint the DOM tree.

Answering your questions:
*1) no

2) nohow

3) yes, ReactJs uses DOM, for example, here is the source code:

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-dom/src/client/ReactDOMFiberComponent.js#L379

and

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-dom/src/client/setInnerHTML.js#L38*

Comment: Hi thanks for response!  let me know if i fully understand your answer, in react virtualDOM, if we have array and each item is <li> ( element ), then we add/remove item from this array react find the diff and change only this <li> element with official browser (appendChild, innerHTML etc...) instend render whole list.

Comment: Hi! Yes, something like this (exactly uses DOM methods under the hood). By the way, for _list_ rendering - in the React documentation there is a description of the algorithm: https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children